# Text Appending override in android

Tags: java, android, textview

I am using `append()` method to append text in `textview` android, but it `override` again and again. I am working to live speech recognition and i am getting live results which i want to set to textview. I am doing like this,

```
  @Override
                    public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
                        if (dsProperties.speechResultFound) return;

                        Boolean valid = (partialResults != null && partialResults.containsKey(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION) &&
                                partialResults.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION) != null &&
                                partialResults.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION).size() > 0 &&
                                !partialResults.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION).get(0).trim().isEmpty());

                        if (valid) {
                            final String droidLiveSpeechResult = partialResults.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION).get(0);

                            if (droidSpeechListener == null) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Droid speech live result = " + droidLiveSpeechResult);
                            } else {
                                // Setting the progress message

                                recognitionProgressMsg.setText(droidLiveSpeechResult);
//                                        setRecognitionProgressMsg(droidLiveSpeechResult);

                                // Sending an update with the droid speech live result
                                droidSpeechListener.onDroidSpeechLiveResult(droidLiveSpeechResult);
                            }

                            if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - dsProperties.pauseAndSpeakTime) > Extensions.MAX_PAUSE_TIME) {
                                dsProperties.speechResultFound = true;

                                droidSpeechPartialResult.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {

                                        // Closing droid speech operations
//                                        closeDroidSpeech();

                                        if (dsProperties.showRecognitionProgressView && dsProperties.oneStepResultVerify) {
                                            // Saving the speech result
                                            dsProperties.oneStepVerifySpeechResult = droidLiveSpeechResult;

                                            restartDroidSpeech.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void run() {
                                                    startDroidSpeechRecognition();
//                                                    abc=abc+" "+droidLiveSpeechResult;
//                                                    droidSpeechListener.onDroidSpeechFinalResult(dsProperties.oneStepVerifySpeechResult);
                                                }

                                            }, Extensions.MAX_PAUSE_TIME);

                                        } else {
                                            if (droidSpeechListener == null) {
                                                Log.i(TAG, "Droid speech final result = " + droidLiveSpeechResult);
                                            } else {

                                                droidSpeechListener.onDroidSpeechLiveResult(droidLiveSpeechResult);
                                                if (dsProperties.continuousSpeechRecognition) {
                                                    // Start droid speech recognition again

                                                    startDroidSpeechRecognition();
                                                } else {

                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                }, Extensions.PARTIAL_DELAY_TIME);
                            } else {
                                dsProperties.pauseAndSpeakTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            }
                        } else {
                            dsProperties.pauseAndSpeakTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        }
                    }

private void setRecognitionProgressMsg(String msg) {    
        if (recognitionProgressMsg != null && msg != null) {    
            recognitionProgressMsg.append(msg);    
        }
}
```

above give is complete code for live recognition and setting live results to textview in bellow function.
can any one correct me?

Comment: what is type of `recognitionProgressMsg`?

Comment: Could you add more code, please? How do you create `msg`? Is it always the full message or just the part to be appended?

Comment: what do you mean by "it override again and again"?

Comment: recognitionProgressMsg is simple textview

Comment: override means after calling this method again, it override previous text set to textview sometime and sometime when i call this method it append same text more then one time

Comment: ok, show how you initialize it, etc.

Comment: private void setRecognitionProgressMsg(String msg) {

        if (recognitionProgressMsg != null && msg != null) {

            recognitionProgressMsg.append(msg);

        }}

Comment: please have a look on about question i have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String a = recognitionProgressMsg.getText().toString();
a+=msg;
recognitionProgressMsg.setText(a);
```

Comment: I am working on live speech to text and i am having live results when user start talking, by using this it copy same text more then one time. for example if i say hello, it set hello 3 times in textview. any help?

Comment: have a look in above question bro.